# Wordpress website get redirect error

Tags: wordpress, redirect

My website is wellinns.com. 
Sometimes redirect to this link
http://wellinns.com/?domain=wellinns.com&reqp=1&reqr=
or this link
http://wellinns.com/TQcPZ/RmaeZ/
I don't know the reason why.

Comment: If that is your website and you don't know the origin of the redirect, check if your site hasn't been hacked.  In my experience, Wordpress is not easy to protect.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I think It is redirecting to an error page, not other page. So, I think it is my config problem.